# Create json fromat in android

Tags: android, json

How can I create a in android json like this.I can create the json object but still facing some problem to make like this.

```
{
"IncidentDetails": {
    "StreetId": "370","StartDate":"21-03-2015","EndDate":"24-03-2015",
    "ImageDetails": [
        {
            "PhoneImageUrl": "\/storage\/sdcard0\/Pictures\/GestiónDeIncidencias\/IMG_20150321_215458_-926186234.jpg",
            "Base64ImageData": "Ioop9RLYCKTAIzRRSGIVGw9s1hvw5HvRRVRYtixan+daM2pCQ\/PH40nQ0uOOKM880guIQTmm044xnNNx",
        },
        {
            "PhoneImageUrl": "\/storage\/sdcard0\/Pictures\/GestiónDeIncidencias\/IMG_20150321_215458_-926186234.jpg",
            "Base64ImageData": "Ioop9RLYCKTAIzRRSGIVGw9s1hvw5HvRRVRYtixan+daM2pCQ\/PH40nQ0uOOKM880guIQTmm044xnNNx",
        },
        {
            "PhoneImageUrl": "\/storage\/sdcard0\/Pictures\/GestiónDeIncidencias\/IMG_20150321_215458_-926186234.jpg",
            "Base64ImageData": "Ioop9RLYCKTAIzRRSGIVGw9s1hvw5HvRRVRYtixan+daM2pCQ\/PH40nQ0uOOKM880guIQTmm044xnNNx",
        }
    ]}
}
```

What I tried in my android code just have a look it giving totally different output

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject IncidentDetails = new JSONObject();

    try 
    {
        IncidentDetails.put("StartDate", EditTextStartText.getText().toString());
        IncidentDetails.put("EndDate", EditTextEndText.getText().toString());
        IncidentDetails.put("StreetId", StreetId);
        jsonArray.put(IncidentDetails);

        for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {

            JSONObject ImageDetails = new JSONObject();
            ImageDetails.put("Base64ImageData", getBase64Image(ReusableClass.imgUrl.get(i)));
            ImageDetails.put("PhoneImageUrl", ReusableClass.imgUrl.get(i));
            jsonArray.put(ImageDetails);
        }

        JSONObject IncidentDetailsObj = new JSONObject();
        IncidentDetailsObj.put("IncidentDetails", jsonArray);

        String jsonStr = IncidentDetailsObj.toString();
```

**My current output**

```
{"IncidentDetails":[{"StreetId":"370","StartDate":"18-03-2015","EndDate":""},{"PhoneImageUrl":"\/storage\/sdcard0\/Pictures\/GestiónDeIncidencias\/IMG_20150318_171451_1389057690.jpg","Base64ImageData":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4SERATGCgaGBYWGDEjJR0oOjM9PDkz\nODdASFxOQERXRTc4UG1RV19iZ2hnPk1xeXBkeFxlZ2P\/2wBDARESEhgVGC8aGi9jQjhCY2NjY2Nj\nY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2P\/wAA"},{"PhoneImageUrl":"\/storage\/sdcard0\/Pictures\/GestiónDeIncidencias\/IMG_20150318_171451_1389057690.jpg","Base64ImageData":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4SERATGCgaGBYWGDEjJR0oOjM9PDkz\nODdASFxOQERXRTc4UG1RV19iZ2hnPk1xeXBkeFxlZ2P\/2wBDARESEhgVGC8aGi9jQjhCY2NjY2Nj\nY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2P\/wAA"}]}
```

Comment: what problems are you facing?

Comment: Not getting exact out put that I want

Comment: what are you getting?

Comment: {"IncidentDetails":[{"StreetId":"370","StartDate":"18-03-2015","EndDate":""},{"PhoneImageUrl":"\/storage\/sdcard0\/Pictures\/GestiónDeIncidencias\/IMG_20150318_171451_1389057690.jpg","Base64ImageData":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ2Y2P\/wAA"},{"PhoneImageUrl":"\/storage\/sdcard0\/Pictures\/GestiónDeIncidencias\/IMG_20150318_171451_1389057690.jpg","Base64ImageData":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4SERATGCgaGBYWGDEjJR0oOjM9PDkz\nODdASFxOQERXRTc4UG"}]}

Comment: what is length? Is it initialized? You need to find out JSONArray size and iterate your loop for that times. More information is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject IncidentDetails = new JSONObject();

    try 
    {
        IncidentDetails.put("StartDate", EditTextStartText.getText().toString());
        IncidentDetails.put("EndDate", EditTextEndText.getText().toString());
        IncidentDetails.put("StreetId", StreetId);


        for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {

            JSONObject ImageDetails = new JSONObject();
            ImageDetails.put("Base64ImageData", getBase64Image(ReusableClass.imgUrl.get(i)));
            ImageDetails.put("PhoneImageUrl", ReusableClass.imgUrl.get(i));
            jsonArray.put(ImageDetails);
        }
    IncidentDetails.put("ImageDetails", jsonArray);

        JSONObject IncidentDetailsObj = new JSONObject();
        IncidentDetailsObj.put("IncidentDetails", IncidentDetails);

        String jsonStr = IncidentDetailsObj.toString();
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you did instead of only posting the code. This won't help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

see answer with comments,

```
   //* IncidentalDetial is an object not an array
   JSONObject IncidentDetails = new JSONObject();
   //* add the first three elements
   IncidentDetails.put("StartDate", EditTextStartText.getText().toString());
   IncidentDetails.put("EndDate", EditTextEndText.getText().toString());
   IncidentDetails.put("StreetId", StreetId);
   //* contruct the imagedetails array
   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
   for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
   {
     JSONObject ImageDetails = new JSONObject();
     ImageDetails.put("Base64ImageData", getBase64Image(ReusableClass.imgUrl.get(i)));
     ImageDetails.put("PhoneImageUrl", ReusableClass.imgUrl.get(i));
     jsonArray.put(ImageDetails);
   }
   //* add the imagedetails array to the incidentDetials object
   IncidentDetails.put(jsonArray);

  JSONObject IncidentDetailsObj = new JSONObject();
  IncidentDetailsObj .put(IncidentDetails);
   String jsonStr = IncidentDetailsObj.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that that this is very common scenario, so there has to be some library that deals it for you :)

I recommend https://code.google.com/p/google-gson - GSON. All you have to do is to prepare POJO class that describes JSON, in your case:

```
public class IncidentDetails {
    IncidentDetails incidentDetails;
}

public class IncidentDetails {
    String streetId;
    String startDate;
    String endDate;
    ImageDetails imageDetails;
}
```

Then do the same with `ImageDetails`. All you have to do then is to create GSON with proper naming policy (it converts automaticcaly class fields names to JSON).

`gson.toJson(incidentDetails)` creates String you desire. `gson.fromString(String json)` will create `IncidentDetails` object from json string.